# See length (count) of query results in workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I just started using MySQL Workbench (6.1). The default limit for queries is 1,000 and that's fine I want to keep that.

But the results from the action output message will therefore always say "1000 rows returned".

Is there a setting to see the number of records that would be returned in the query had their been no limit? For sanity checking query results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is late by a few years, but I think you're asking for a way to see total row count in the bottom of the results pane, like in SQL Server. In SQL Server, you would also go in the messages pane and it would say how many rows were returned. I was actually looking for exactly what you were asking for as well, and seems like there is no way to find that. If you have an ID in your table that is just numeric and is in numeric order, you could order by ID desc and look at the biggest number there. That is what I've decided to do.

Comment: Strange that the accepted answer was changed to this one, which essentially says the same as mine: there is no direct way to get that number (just 3 years later).

Answer (score 3):

The result is not always "1000 rows returned". If there are less records than that you will get the actual count. If you want to know the total number of rows in a table do a `select count(*) from table`. Alternatively, you can switch off the automatic limit and have all records returned by MySQL Workbench, but that can be time + memory consuming for large tables.

Comment: OK but the question is how to get the count of a query result show up, regardless of limit and without having to count(*) (myquery). IS there a setting somewhere that shows what the length of the query is without actually having to run a count query with the results?

Comment: I think I answered your question pretty well, but if you insist on a clear-as-mud answer: no, there's no setting or something. How can a client know the possible count without querying the count? In that case however, you could just do it yourself. It's just a waste of CPU cycles to let WB determine this all the time too.

Comment: The thing that prompted the question though was that when I tried to count (*) (myquery) foo the result, for whatever reason, took a very long time to calculate. Which was odd since the query itself ran very fast.

Comment: phpMyAdmin does it well. Well, this does not answer your question since you're using workbench, however, you may try phpmyadmin to see. It will show you like this for example: "Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 3,225 total, Query took 2.1351 sec)"

Comment: In workbench, in the dropdown menu at the top, set it to dont limit
Then run the query to extract data from table
Then under the output pane below, the total count of the query results will be displayed in the message column

Answer (score 3):

I think removing the row limit will help. By default, MySQL workbench will limit the result set to 1000 rows but you can always disable the limit. Check out https://superuser.com/questions/240291/how-to-remove-1000-row-limit-in-mysql-workbench-queries on how to do that.

Comment: This answer worked for me. After applying the change, you need to see output to get the rows returned by the executed query

Answer (score 1):

In workbench, in the dropdown menu at the top, set it to dont limit Then run the query to extract data from table Then under the output pane below, the total count of the query results will be displayed in the message column

Answer (score 1):

You can run a second query to check that

```
select count(*) from (your original query) as t;
```

this will return the total rows in actual result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL count function. It returns the count of the total number of rows a query returns.

A sample query:

```
select count(*) from tableName where field1 = value1
```